# Serializing the copying of multiple sets of files

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

When I use the Nautilus to copy files from my desktop to a usb key, or over wifi, I frequently start copying a set of files from a to b, then navigate elsewhere and copy another set of files from c to b.   There's a danger that  I run out of disk space, or one of the files might be too large to fit on the destination device's file system, or some other error occurs, and I then have no idea which files were copied and which weren't.   Additionally, multiple writes to a USB device are extremely slow and tend to cause the OS as a whole (or at least my experience of it using Unity) to slow down.

Copying one set of files at a time is a sensible workaround but what would be better would be if I could throw a bunch of files at an app which would - no matter how many files it was given - copy them one at a time, checking before each individual file that it would fit, and, if there IS an error, providing a list of which files did/didn't copy successfully so I could correct the problem and continue where I left off. It would be even better if the files I've lined up are displayed in such a way that I could remove them from the "about the copy" list if I change my mind before copying commences.

Does such a tool exist?  Is there some other, better way of doing what I'm attempting to do here? I'd prefer a graphical solution.

Comment: I think you can use `rsync` to do what you want. It is a very powerful tool, with many options. You can start with something straight-forward and learn new options gradually. I have found the following command line useful for cases similar to yours: `sudo rsync-Havn source-dir/ target-dir`

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use rsync as suggested in the comment. As you seem to prefer a GUI solution I would recommend using [freefilesync](http://www.freefilesync.org/).

The usage is very straightforward:

1. Choose left and right directories.
2. Press Compare.
3. Select synchronization settings.
4. Press Synchronize to begin synchronization.

Freefilesync also supports batch jobs.